# When was Shlomo HaMelech anointed king?

Tags: sources-mekorot, parshanut-torah-comment, king-david, melachim-kings-book-of, king-solomon

When (day, month, year) was Shlomo HaMelech anointed king, as according to the pasuk below?

> 1 Kings 1:45 And Zadok the priest and Nathan the prophet have anointed
> him king in Gihon, and they have come up from their rejoicing, and
> (therefore) the city was turbulent, this is the noise you have heard.
>
> https://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/15885/jewish/Chapter-1.htm/showrashi/true

Answer (score 1):

[image]

As far as the year, according to the Seder HaDoros HaKotzair (p.29) it writes that he was born in the year 2912. He was then crowned when he was 12 years old which takes us to 2924 and reigned for a total of 40 years (i.e. until he was 52) which is the year 2964 when he died.

Comment: But Shlomo was annointed as king while David was still alive, some time before his reign actually began upon David's death

Comment: In either case, surely, somebody recorded the day, month?

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question. The question asks when Sh'lomo was anointed according to I Kings 1:45, but this answer doesn't use that verse.

Comment: She is looking for the "day, month, year" that he was anointed king - I provided the year...